# Formula losing date formatting

Tags: excel, date, formatting, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have been using the following as a formula array beginning in column R2 for an Excel spreadsheet that combines the data from four columns:

```
=L2&" "&N2&" "&Q2&" "&P2
```

Column L contains the date in the following format: `2/23/2015`.

The formula used to show the date as shown above, but now for some reason the format has changed to go from `2/23/2015` to `42081`.

I can't seem to get date to show as it once did. Also the Excel spreadsheet I apply this to is downloaded from a different source each day so I don't know if default formatting has changed even though the data is exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you concatenate like that you just get the values not the formatting because number formatting doesn't apply in the text string created. You can use `TEXT` function to dictate the format in this context, e.g.

`=TEXT(L2,"m/d/yyyy")&" "&N2&" "&Q2&" "&P2`

Answer (score 1):

With MDY convention, if L2 is formatted as Text prior to entry then keying in `2/23/2015` would preserve that display in a formula that concatenates it with other strings. Similarly if not keyed but entered with `Ctrl`+`:`.

If L2 is formatted as General or Short Date the date index will be concatenated (`42081` in the example above) though the display in L2 will not change.

While a change in formatting may be the most likely explanation (and a solution provided by @barry) another possibility is a change in the date convention from DMY. In which case `2/23/2015` would have displayed and concatenated as that even in a cell formatted as Short Date. `2/12/2015` in that case however would have displayed as such but in the 1900 date system concatenated as `42340` - the date serial number for December 2, not February 12.